# top (current) Pagein Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

there isn't a clear answer to this I've found, though plenty of similar questions with partial answers buried deep, and the answers are very old and outdated.

On Android OS 12, suppose I'm doing permissions stuff, I've switched away from my app to the settings app, and then switched back, and I need to find the currently displaying (top) Page, and refresh its UI based on the new permissions? How do I find the current page?

I have this so far, but it absolutely does not work.

```
public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
{            
    base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Page p = App.Current.MainPage;
    if (p.Navigation != null && p.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count != 0 && p.Navigation.NavigationStack[0] != null)
    {
        Page sp = p.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
        if (sp != null) p = sp;
    }
    BaseViewModel bvm = (p.BindingContext as BaseViewModel);
    bvm.UpdateUIBasedOnPermissions();
}
```

Comment: What does the 'not work' mean? The method wasn't called or the  'Page p' got null or the other thing?

Comment: I had test your code. When I set the mainpage as the navigation page in the App.xaml.cs, `Page sp = p.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();` will get the current page.